# Historical trend reporting limitation: How far back in time?

Tags: reporting, opportunity

Just set up historical trend reporting for opportunities, but I was curious about one of the noted limitations:

> You can make up to three months of data available for historical trend reporting.

Does this mean that the historical data saved is a rolling list of the last three months (e.g. I could view historical changes from May 18 of this year until now, but could not see what changed before that)?

So this means this report would not work to see what stage an opportunity was at on Jan 1 of this year compared to what it is now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct!

Historical trending in Salesforce is subject to certain limits on the time during which data is tracked, the number of rows of data, and the fields and objects you can track. These limits are designed to restrict the data set so that reports return data quickly.

> You can make up to three months of data available for historical trend
>   reporting.
>
> Salesforce retains historical data for the previous **three months**, plus
>   the **current month**.

This comes under the [Limitations on Historical Trend Reporting](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/reports_historical_limits.htm).

When I enabled this feature in my developer org, I have received the following email from Salesforce.com

> A new custom report type, Case with Historical Trending, is available.
>   This report type can compare data for up to five points in time
>   (snapshots) within the previous three full months and all days so far
>   in the current month.
>
> Space is available for up to 5 million records. You are alerted by
>   email if you reach 70% of the limit. To avoid hitting the limit, use
>   the Historical Trending setup page to configure the amount of data for
>   which history is captured.

Comment: If I wanted to go beyond the 3 month limit, is that where I would need to utilize Reporting Snapshots?

Comment: Yes, This should work. Data captured from Historical Trending should be stored into the custom object on a daily basis. By doing this, you can get the history beyond 3 months time.